# Can I hold onto the address returned by std::initializer_list<T>::begin()?

Tags: c++, embedded, initializer-list, static-initialization

I have a number of static instances of a class of data which hold onto arrays of integers, simplied in the following:

```
class ReadableIds
{
public:
  const int * ids;
  ReadableIds( const int * _ids ) : ids(_ids) { }

  // ... a bunch of methods that operate on ids, not germane to the discussion
};
```

I currently populate them in the following way at filescope:

```
foo.cpp:

//
static const int phase_one_ids[] = { 1, 10, 3, 2, -1 };
static ReadableIds phase_one( phase_one_ids );

static const int phase_two_ids[] = { 31, 11, 23, 542, 11, 88, -1 };
static ReadableIds phase_two( phase_two_ids );
```

However, I really want them to be defined inline for legibility reasons ( the class is more complicated with other arguments passed to the constructor)

```
static ReadableIds phase_one( { 1, 10, 3, 2, -1 }, ... other args );
static ReadableIds phase_two( { 31, 11, 23, 542, 11, 88, -1 }, ... other args );
```

The only way I can compile this is if I introduce a std::initializer_list:

```
class ReadableIds
{
public:
    ReadableIds(const std::initializer_list<int> & _ids ) : 
        ids(_ids.begin())  // take address of initializer_list !!
    {
    }
};
```

But my understanding is that the std::initializer_list is temporary, so holding the address to that data is wrong.

**Question**: Without allocating memory dynamically, is there a solution to this to allow better syntax? Doing a copy results in the static memory consumption, and the copy of the data, and in my use case that isn't viable.

Comment: It is temporary for the duration of the constructor call. You should copy the content to a member variable (e.g. a std::vector)

Comment: @PepijnKramer - In my use case I do not want to allocate off the heap.

Comment: The list of values is going to need to live somewhere.  You either use an array, which means possible wasted space if you just use some default max size or that `ReadableIds` needs to become a template. Alternatively you can do dynamic allocation by storing those values into a `vector`

Comment: Prefer `std::initializer_list<int> _ids`, it allows a compiler to better optimize the code with using CPU registers for values - it passes `_ids`'s begin and end through CPU registers and uses them directly, otherwise the code uses indirections of `_ids` address.

Comment: @273K the following link is in regards to your now deleted answer: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#6

Comment: `static ReadableIds xphase_one([]{ static int const data[]{ 1, 10, 3, 2, -1 }; return data; }());`

Comment: I'm not a fan of macros, but you can make it prettier with `#define DATA(...) []{ static int const data[]{ __VA_ARGS__ }; return data; }()`

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, my apologies I meant [] and have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @RaymondChen When I create the satic declaration const int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, -1 } there is no dynamic allocation; it is a static allocation. There is no length required; the compiler can determine how much storage is required in the data segment of the program. I am trying to avoid having to hit the heap, which is the case in my original implementation. It is simply that it is too verbose in my actual use case.

Comment: `template<std::size_t N> class ReadableIds { public: std::array<int, N> my_ids; ReadableIds(std::array<int, N> const& ids) : my_ids(ids) {} };` Now you have a copy in `my_ids`. `auto x = ReadableIdx(std::array{1,2,3});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't store the result of `_ids.begin()`, or rather: You can store it, but can't dereference it after the initialization of `phase_two` where it becomes a dangling pointer.

Your requirements seem to be that

1. `ReadableIds` doesn't actually store the elements itself.
2. There is no need to add a named variable to store the elements.
3. No dynamic storage duration for the elements either.

Then the only way is to store the elements in a temporary array object. The problem is that temporaries are normally destroyed after full-expression in which they are manifested, which is not what you want.

`std::initializer_list` construction can extend the lifetime to that of the `std::initializer_list` object itself, but if you don't want to name a variable you now didn't do anything but shift the problem to extending the lifetime of the temporary `std::initializer_list` object.

The only way to extend the lifetime of a temporary object to that of a class object is to store a reference (in)to the temporary object directly in the class and initializing it *immediately* with the newly manifested temporary via braced aggregate initialization.

So, you can do:

```
// DON'T USE THIS!

class ReadableIds
{
public:
    // must be aggregate, no constructors!

    std::initializer_list<int>&& _ids; // must be reference!
    // other aggregate elements
};
```

Now you may use the syntax

```
// DON'T USE THIS!

// must be braces!
static ReadableIds phase_one{ { 1, 10, 3, 2, -1 },
    /*initializers for other aggregate elements*/ };
```

and the array referenced by `_ids` will live as long as `phase_one`, but it won't be copied or have its lifetime extended if `phase_one` is copied/moved! A copy will refer to the same array and `std::initializer_list` object! Copying/moving `std::initializer_list` explicitly also wont copy/move or extend the lifetime of the underlying array!

In particular, if `phase_one` wasn't a static storage duration object, then the array will not live until the end of the program, only ever until the end of the scope in which `phase_one` is declared.

The lifetime extension also doesn't work if you use parentheses instead of braces for initialization of `phase_one` or if you insert a constructor.

All in all I would not recommend this. It is very fragile and not worth it to avoid naming one extra variable. (I would also not be sure that compilers correctly implement this special case of nested lifetime extension.)

Also, reconsider whether the first requirement really is necessary. It is easy enough to make the class a template that automatically deduces the correct size for an internal array.

---

A slightly safer variation would be to use an array instead of `std::initializer_list`. In that case you need to template the class on the size of the array though:

```
// DON'T USE THIS!

template<std::size_t N>
class ReadableIds
{
public:
    // must be aggregate, no constructors!

    int (&&_ids)[N]; // must be reference!
    // other aggregate elements
};
```

The requirements on the initialization still apply, but there is less potential on mistakenly copying `_ids`.